# Answers that hint at the right answer but don't quite get there

Tags: discussion

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492178/updating-java-breaks-eclipse-running?noredirect=1#comment41630960_26492178) is my question. I received two answers quickly and they pointed me in the right direction but didn't really answer the question and are both one line. I don't really flag answers very often. Are they flagworthy or just kind of weak?

Comment: If you feel they pointed you in the right direction but didn't provide the entire solution on their own, what's stopping you from adding a complete answer yourself and accepting that? It's perfectly fine to do that as long as you credit the other answers for helping you.

Comment: @ivarni look at the question. That's what I did

Comment: Oh right. I didn't notice the link, sorry.

Comment: I often upvote answers that point me in the right direction, even if they don't completely solve my problem.  They were helpful.  I find it strange to downvote for being helpful, but not helpful _enough_.  (Though as always you're free to vote as you wish.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weak, but not flag-worthy. They definitely are attempting to answer the question.

Comment: I agree but they are one line and would leave the basic eclipse user still unable to fix his problem

Comment: Feel free to down vote if you think they aren't helpful. I'm just saying I'm pretty sure a "not an answer" or "very low quality" flag would be disputed/declined.

Answer (score 3):

If they are sub-optimal then down vote them. You could consider leaving a comment that they didn't quite answer completely so you didn't find them completely helpful.

But don't flag them - your flag should get declined because they are still answers.